# Web development for iPad: how to make safari view non-draggable

Tags: ipad, safari, web, drag

I'm making a web project that is fitted to the iPad screen. I'm trying to make it look as much like a native app as possible. It is loaded in safari or atomic browser. What I'm trying to find out is if it's possible to eliminate the drag and even the zoom functions of one of those browsers for just that site.

To rephrase, I want to make my site fixed on the screen at all times. The issue is, a user will try to hit a button and it will drag the screen.

PS. An additional question is how I can make it so images don't have the "save as" functionality if held down I tried putting a span over the images, and that worked for firefox, but not iPad safari.

If you can solve any or all of these, you would have my biggest thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that there are several metatags that you can put in your js file which keep the screen fixed. Good stuff on that is here: 
http://jakeboyles.com/2011/01/16/how-to-build-an-iphone-and-ipad-web-app/

As far as the "save as" issue, I don't know yet, that part of my app development hasn't been solved.